# How do I “average” out the position vectors of each independent ball, so all the balls only have one color when I plug in an image node?

Tags: texturing, uv

Is there a node combination to get the average of the position vectors of each individual ball so when I plug in an image node the balls act like pixels?[image]

Comment: Is the idea to form an image when the balls land in place?

Comment: yes, that is the plan

Comment: Use the UV project modifier. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGc2LPO14wA

Comment: i'ts not like that I need each ball to only be one color

Comment: Are you planning on viewing it only from that angle (side view), or are you planning to be able to move the camera position?

Comment: Is it one object for all the balls or one object per ball? Anyway, as you're using UV input, if each ball UV is scaled down to zero, will have one color.